# Messenger ChatBot open link in default browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a messenger chatbot that show URL Buttons. When the user tap on the URL Button a webview is opened. I'd like the user to be redirected on the default browser instead of opening the webview, is this achievable in any way? Or is there any [ugly] workaround to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Hello Stefano! Did you find a workaround for this? I need the same behaviour. Thank you!

Comment: Nope sorry, it seems not possible

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to `URL button` instead of `webview` inside your response options. You can set `type` to `url` and then pass `urlbutton` params. How I am doing this is as follows.

```
type: 'url',
urlButton: {
  url: 'somewhere.com',
  title: 'Title'
},
```

Did you try this before adding some comment? This is the exact payload I am sending in the body and it opens the URL in new window. Please verify and let me know if you find any difficulty.

```
{ attachment: 
  { type: 'template',
    payload: 
     { template_type: 'button',
       text: 'xyz',
       buttons: [ { type: 'web_url',
        url: 'http://www.google.com',
       title: 'New Button' } ] 
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: from the documentation: "The URL Button opens a webpage in the Messenger webview" https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/buttons/url/

Comment: @StefanoGiacone just edited the answer with exact code from a code sample that I am using. Please verify and let me know if you find any more issues?